# How to insert numerical values in a cell of a Google Sheet and how I can find their sum?

Tags: google-sheets, mobile, android

I use Google Sheets mobile(Android).
I have one column with dates, and anoter column where in each cell I want to input several numerical values that corespond in each date, and in a third column the sum of those numerical values ( actually I plan to do 50 pushups every day for 5 days in several sets in each days, but I dont know the number of the daily sets).
[image: 5 days 50 pushups]

The problem is that when I input numbers in column B seperated by either commas or spaces, the sheet converts the numbers into a date. 
For example when I insert in B2 5,5,2 it converts it in 5 5 2002
[image]

How can avoid this problem?
(maybe with something like an arraylist? )
And if there is solution to the above problem, is there any way to input in the C column the sum of those numbers?

---

I don't know the number of columns, each time the number of sets are different

Comment: Use a column for each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try entering numbers in **B** column like:

- **`'5,5,2`**

[image]

or

- **`="5,5,2"`**

[image]

or

- **`=TEXT(; "5,5,2")`**

[image]

or

- **`=T("5,5,2")`**

[image]

and then **`SUM`** it with a formula like:

**`=SUM(SPLIT(B247;",";1;0))`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" way to use a spreadsheet is to put each value on separate cells, so instead of

```
5,5,2
```

use

```
  A | B    |   C |   D |  E  | 
date| sets |     |     | sum |
 ...|     5|    5|    2| ... |
```

where A, B, C, D and E are built-in column headers.

Alternatives

1. Use another separator like `|`.
2. Prepend `'` to prevent the automatic conversion to date.
3. Change the regional locale. I.E. Mexico doesn't convert `5,5,2` to date.
4. Add mininum 4 values something like `5,5,2,0`.
5. To use a column for each value, if you don't know how many values will be, change the column order, `date | sum | set` and use `=SUM(C2:2)` to make the sum for each row. NOTE: If you will have many values use an array formula or `MMULT` instead.